# How To Have Multiple Images 'Fall'

Tags: java, android, image

How would I go about making different images 'fall' down to the bottom of the device's screen, and then repeat? While having the images 'fall' down at different times? What I mean by 'falling down' is that, for a few examples, it is raining on my app. Or there is a wave of enemies making their way down the device's screen towards the user's player. How could I make a raindrop image 'fall' down repeatedly to make it look like it is raining on my app?? Or make enemies go down the screen towards the user's player, such as a space shooter game?

I have tried using the `loop()` function but whatever I tried it didn't work.

Comment: What type of loop() should i use?

Comment: Should i use a `loop();` at all for what I want to do??

Comment: @CommonWares Can you help me?